# Is it possible to generate javadoc where links to a specific url are opened in a new tab?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I included the android reference in my javadoc generation by using

```
options {
    linksOffline "https://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
}
```

in a gradle Javadoc task.

This works fine and i get the correct link to the android reference.
The issue i am having is that the default behaviour of the generated javadoc html is to open the link in a frame which is not allowed.
(Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html?is-external=true does not permit cross-origin framing.)

Is there a way to generate the javadoc html in a way that links to https://developer.android.com/reference are opened in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution for now is just a gradle task of type exec that depends on the javadoc task which executes a shell script that can do this this.

```
task("javadocAndroidReferenceInTabs", type: Exec, dependsOn: javadocTask) {
    executable "sh"
    args "android_ref_new_tab.sh", "javadoc_path"
}
```

android_ref_new_tab.sh:

```
grep -rl 'href=\"https:\/\/d\.android\.com\/reference' $1 | xargs sed -i '' 's/href=\"https:\/\/d\.android\.com\/reference/target=\"_blank\" href=\"https:\/\/d\.android\.com\/reference/g'
```

This adds target="_blank" to all android reference links which makes them open in a new tab.

Comment: this is interesting. Where do you put the script android_ref_new_tab.sh? Thanks...

Comment: In the same folder as the build.gradle file containing the task.